# Unpivot Multiple rows to columns and split columns to sub-sets

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have attached an expected solution done with PowerQuery. However, I'll like to know how this can be done with R.

My data looks like this:

[image: Before]

Desired outcome:

[image: Expected Outcome]

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 1):

I use tidyverse and dplyr for data wrangling.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

## Creating a dummy dataframe

df = data.frame(ResponseID=1:10,  
              Status=c("Complete","Incomplete","Complete","Complete","Incomplete","Complete","Incomplete","Complete","Complete","Incomplete"),
                q1 = sample(1:10,10, replace = T),
                q2a=sample(1:10,10, replace = T),
                q2b=sample(1:10,10, replace = T),
                q2c=sample(1:10,10, replace = T),
                q2d=sample(1:10,10, replace = T),
                q2e=sample(1:10,10, replace = T),
                q2f=sample(1:10,10, replace = T),
                q2g=sample(1:10,10, replace = T),
                q2h=sample(1:10,10, replace = T),
                q2i=sample(1:10,10, replace = T),
                q2j=sample(1:10,10, replace = T),
                q10a=sample(1:10,10, replace = T),
                q10b=sample(1:10,10, replace = T),
                q10c=sample(1:10,10, replace = T),
                q10d=sample(1:10,10, replace = T),
                q10e=sample(1:10,10, replace = T)
                )


   ResponseID     Status q1 q2a q2b q2c q2d q2e q2f q2g q2h q2i q2j q10a q10b q10c q10d q10e
1           1   Complete  9   8   6   1  10   4   4   4   3   1   4    1    7    1   10    5
2           2 Incomplete  1  10  10   4   1   6   2   2   4   9   4    3    8    1    9   10
3           3   Complete 10   8   1   5   3   4   8   7   8   2   8    5    3   10    9    1
4           4   Complete  1  10   3   5   7   4   9   3   1   4   7    9    4    7    9   10
5           5 Incomplete  7   2   7   6   7   6   5   1   4  10   2    9   10    7    6    7
6           6   Complete  6   8   5   4   5   7   2   1   2   5   3    7    9    2    1    7
7           7 Incomplete 10   5   2   9   5   5   8   5   4   6   5    7    6    9    5    8
8           8   Complete  7   4   1   8   8   1   3   5   9   7   1    4    5    9    5    1
9           9   Complete  4   5  10   8   9   6   6   6   1   7   5    7    7    4    6    9
10         10 Incomplete  3   7   3   1   9  10   2   5  10   3   2    7    3    6    7    9

## Wider to longer
df1 = df %>%
  pivot_longer(!c(ResponseID,Status), names_to = "Question", values_to = "Values")

## Extracting the last alphabet 
df1$Alphabet=ifelse(str_detect(df1$Question, "[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]")==T,substr(df1$Question, nchar(df1$Question) - 1 + 1, nchar(df1$Question)),"a")

df1$AlphaToNo = match(df1$Alphabet,letters)
df1$Q =  sub('(\\d+).*', '\\1', df1$Question)

df2 = df1 %>%
  group_by(ResponseID, Q,AlphaToNo) %>%
  summarise(SumValues=sum(Values)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = AlphaToNo, values_from = SumValues) %>%
  arrange(ResponseID,Q)
  
df2[is.na(df2)] <- 0


## Final Output

> head(df2,15)
# A tibble: 15 x 12
# Groups:   ResponseID, Q [15]
   ResponseID Q       `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`  `10`
        <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1          1 q1        9     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 2          1 q10       1     7     1    10     5     0     0     0     0     0
 3          1 q2        8     6     1    10     4     4     4     3     1     4
 4          2 q1        1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 5          2 q10       3     8     1     9    10     0     0     0     0     0
 6          2 q2       10    10     4     1     6     2     2     4     9     4
 7          3 q1       10     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 8          3 q10       5     3    10     9     1     0     0     0     0     0
 9          3 q2        8     1     5     3     4     8     7     8     2     8
10          4 q1        1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
11          4 q10       9     4     7     9    10     0     0     0     0     0
12          4 q2       10     3     5     7     4     9     3     1     4     7
13          5 q1        7     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
14          5 q10       9    10     7     6     7     0     0     0     0     0
15          5 q2        2     7     6     7     6     5     1     4    10     2
```